# Avoid duplicating calculations when filtering by an aggregate of an aggregate?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, teradata

I am trying to pull monthly sales of stores which exceeded sales of 10,000 units per month at least 6 months in the past year.  My source sales table is daily.  Therefore, I am calculating sales for all months for all stores, then figuring out which ones exceeded 10,000 units 6 times, and using that list of stores as a filter for a query in which I calculate all months for the filtered stores.

Thus, I'm essentially doing the same aggregate calculation `sum(units_sold)` twice in the same query:

```
select
    store_location,
    sales_date - extract(day from sales_date) + 1 as sales_month,
    sum(units_sold) as monthly_sales,   /* I already calculated this!  How to re-use? */
    case when sum(units_sold) > 10000 then 1 else 0 end as exceeded_10000 

from
    daily_sales

where
    sales_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' and
    store_location in (
        select
            store_location
        from (
                select
                    store_location,
                    sales_date - extract(day from sales_date) + 1 as sales_month,
                    case when sum(units_sold) > 10000 then 1 else 0 end as exceeded_10000   /* evaluated per month, per store */
                from
                    daily_sales
                where
                    sales_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31'
                group by
                    store_location,
                    sales_date - extract(day from sales_date) + 1
        ) a
        group by
            store_location
        having
            sum(exceeded_10000) > 6   /* which stores had 6 months over 10000 ? */ 
    )

group by
    store_location,
    sales_date - extract(day from sales_date) + 1
```

This seems inefficient -- I've already computed `sum(units_sold)` by month in the inner (filtering) query, but I can't figure out a way to re-use those monthly totals.  You'll note that query b does NOT group by month, by necessity, since it is adding up the number of months in which sales exceeded 10,000 -- that's the aggregate of an aggregate I refer to in the title.

Teradata does not support the PIVOT function, and I'd prefer not to use a massive series of CASE WHEN's to emulate a pivot and then check each month on a single row.

Is there a way to make this query more efficient?  To re-use the monthly sales totals I already calculated in the inner query?  Could it be simplified on a different RDBMS platform instead of Teradata?  Thank you.

Comment: That's shouldn't be inefficient... any sane SQL engine, with a stable function (such as SUM()), should know that if you provide the same input twice, it will produce the same output.

Comment: Interesting.  I looked at the execution plan via EXPLAIN, and there are 3 SUM steps.  I would expect 2 -- first to sum up sales per store per month, and then to sum 'exceeded_10000' to find the qualifying stores.  The 3rd SUM is sourced from a previously-created spool and the time estimate is under a second... not sure if that is because it is using the previously-calculated SUMs, as you indicate it should, or just that the list has been filtered down greatly at this point.  Will try to investigate further, thanks.

Comment: Well, I could be mistaken; there could be mitigating factors. But even so, adding numbers is *not* an expensive operation, compared to the other things your query is doing.

Comment: Your GROUP BY clauses are going to be reflected in the EXPLAIN as sum step aggregations regardless of the existence of a scalar aggregation being done in the query. `EXPLAIN SELECT DatabaseName FROM DBC.DiskSpace GROUP BY DatabaseName;` and `EXPLAIN SELECT DatabaseName, MAX(CurrentPerm) FROM DBC.DiskSpace GROUP BY DatabaseName;` both show a SUM step aggregation taking place.

Comment: @Flimzy -- I experimented by setting a very high and very low criteria for the HAVING clause.  When it was low, and hardly any stores were filtered, it took 1.7x longer to run than when the criteria was high (which filtered nearly all stores).  So it appears that the engine may not be "sane" as you suggested :)

Comment: @ExactaBox: That doesn't sound like it relates to SUM() directly at all. Your inner query returning more rows will, obviously, make the outter query more expensive.

Comment: @Flimzy -- I'm not claiming specifically that the SUM() function is slowing things down.  The point is that *everything* requested in the outer-most query has already been retrieved, grouped and calculated via the inner-most query.  Like you stated, it would make sense if the DBMS engine cached it and re-used it all, but it doesn't appear that is happening, it may not be recognizing that it is the "same input" as you said.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query doesn't seem to do what you want.  The outside query is grouping by month, which shouldn't be necessary.

The following query returns the locations that have more than 6 months with more than 10,000 in sales:

```
select store_location, sum(month_units_sold) as totalunits,
        sum(exceeded_10000) as months_over_10000
from (select store_location,
             sales_date - extract(day from sales_date) + 1 as sales_month,
             sum(units_sold) as month_units_sold
             (case when sum(units_sold) > 10000 then 1 else 0 end) as exceeded_10000   /* evaluated per month, per store */
      from daily_sales
      where sales_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31'
      group by store_location, sales_date - extract(day from sales_date) + 1
    ) t
group by store_location
having sum(exceeded_10000) >= 6
```

If you want information about each store by month, then calculate the number of months exceeded using window functions:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             SUM(exceeded_10000) over (partition by store_location) s MonthsExceeded10000
      from (select store_location,
                   sales_date - extract(day from sales_date) + 1 as sales_month,
                   sum(units_sold) as month_units_sold
                   (case when sum(units_sold) > 10000 then 1 else 0 end) as exceeded_10000   /* evaluated per month, per store */
            from daily_sales
            where sales_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31'
            group by store_location, sales_date - extract(day from sales_date) + 1
          ) t
    ) t
where MonthsExceeded10000
```

Comment: I need to display each month's sales for the stores that qualify.  Yours looks like it will tell me the annual sales for those stores, which is not my goal.

Comment: Your middle query, where you SUM(exceeded_10000), has no GROUP BY clause.  If you GROUP BY store & month, then SUM(exceeded_10000) will never be > 1.  If you GROUP BY store only, then you don't have the monthly sales available to pass to the outer-most query.  I appreciate your help but I can easily write the queries you've suggested -- I'm asking the question because the requirements are more complex than that.

Comment: @ExactaBox . . . In my mind, there was definitely a `partition` clause.  It just didn't make it into the query.  I fixed that.  Without the partition, the query is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: OK this is cool.  I've used window functions for RANK, ROW_NUMBER, etc but never as a sum.  The execution plan is shorter and in my testing the query runs between 10 and 60% faster than my original (I think the variance is due to server load, this is a shared data warehouse).  Thanks!